# Silverlight handling multiple key press combinations

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Silverlight application in which I catch certain key presses such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to perform some action.  However, I want to be able to handle multiple keys pressed at the same time such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or something like that.  Is there any way to do that in Silverlight, and if so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the [ModifierKeys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys(v=VS.95).aspx) to check for multiple key press combinations. See [Silverlight Keyboard Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015(VS.95).aspx) for code samples and more information.

```
void Canvas_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //check for the specific 'v' key, then check modifiers
    if (e.Key==Key.V) { 
        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control) {
        //specific Ctrl+V action here
        }
    } // else ignore the keystroke
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling key combinations like Cntrl+X is very problematic with Silverlight as your running in a browser which will, probably, use most Cntrl combinations itself. Then given that you probably need to support multiple browsers such as IE, Firefox, etc I recommend you give up.

Hence I limit Silverlight key combinations to shift only.