# How I can capture multiple keys?

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I need to capture multiple keys in the same time like "Shift+Insert" how I can use this using System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs. I've written some code but it doesn't work:

```
 private void Grid1KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Shift && e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Insert)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Could anyone help me?

Note: In silverlight project you are not allowed to use "System.Windows.Forms".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619749/silverlight-handling-multiple-key-press-combinations

Comment: Yes, but still there is a problem when I pressed shift+insert it returns none for Keyboard.Modifiers.

Comment: it happened in debug mode thank you for your answer. it was correct.

Answer (score 4):

Rather try something like

```
if (e.Shift && e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Insert)
{
    //do something
}
```

Have a look at [KeyEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx)

> A KeyEventArgs, which specifies the key the user pressed and whether
>   any modifier keys (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>) were pressed at the same
>   time, is passed with each <kbd>KeyDown</kbd> or <kbd>KeyUp</kbd> event.

You could also look at [KeyEventArgs.Modifiers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers.aspx)

> Gets the modifier flags for a <kbd>KeyDown</kbd> or <kbd>KeyUp</kbd> event. The flags
>   indicate which combination of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys was pressed.

Comment: but it is not in windows form project it in silverlight project.

Comment: these are not present in system.windows.input.keyevent args (for silverlight/wpf) only in the forms equivalent. This is specifically part of the question